# Парсить/рендерить javascript сайта на сервере

Tags: php, javascript, asp.net, asp

Добрый день. Есть html который получаю по запросу. Html содержит javascript код document.write и прочие функции по изменению контента. Нужно на серверной стороне получить готовый html с уже выполненными скриптами. 
На сервере есть возможность использовать несколько вариантов языков. Как минимум php, asp.net.

Скажите, это возможно?
Сейчас сделан костыль. На винде стартует обычное десктопное приложение с эксплорером, после загрузки полученный html уезжает на сервер для парсинга. Но это коряво.

Comment: JS - скриптовый язык, который должен работать на стороне клиента (по крайней мере, так было до Node.js). Для генерации содержимого на сервер-сайде используются языки типа PHP

Comment: Спасибо, я знаю, что и для чего первоначально сделано. Но это не ответ на мой вопрос. Мне нужно получить html который генерится скриптом, после чего пропарсить (это я умею и есть куча механизмов). И все это должно быть сделано на сервере.

Comment: Если бы я хотел дать ответ на ваш вопрос, я бы дал ответ, а не комментарий.

Comment: @andr2510, попробуйте использовать какие-нибудь инструменты тестирования типа seleium'а. В seleinum'е вроде как можно получить html, обработанный js. Для питона пример есть [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739514), для php должно быть аналогично.

Answer (score 1):

то что js это сугубо клиентский язык это неправда , это вполне себе язык общего назначение работающего на спецификации ECMAScript , на его базе работает также (JavaScript, JScript и ActionScript) . node js использует движок v8 . Если вы пишете тесты то смотрите в сторону selenium мощнейшая вещь . Если пишете парсер и вам нужны результаты AJAX то разбирайте код , благо есть встроенные во все браузеры средства отладки или firebug для FF и запрашивайте страницы обработчики AJAX отдельно .

Comment: Проблема в том, что автору надо парсить не на клиенте (в браузере), а на сервере (т.е. там, откуда браузер должен брать данные). Поэтому необходим эмулятор js (либо эмулятор браузера типа selenium'a) на сервере. Не работал с nodejs, может быть им тоже можно на сервере это дело обработать.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте PHP browserext. У них даже есть документация на русском: https://github.com/scraperlab/browserext/blob/master/README-RU.md